# Localized title for Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, localization, sign-in-with-apple

I was implementing Apple's new 'Sign in with Apple' feature in my Xamarin iOS application. Apple allowed titles for this are - "Continue with Apple", "Sign in with Apple" and "Sign up with Apple"(iOS 13.2 and above). How can I localize them? I have my application in both English and French. Need to localize the title in French application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use `ASAuthoizationAppleIDButton` then it will automatically use the device locale.

Comment: @Paulw11 i tried but it didn't change the language of the button which was rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still search for an answer, due to "Guideline 4.0 - Design", you should use the following localized versions :

- English : "Sign in with Apple"
- French : "Connexion avec Apple"

Otherwise, your app will be rejected.

Comment: You can't change the title for this label. Not sure what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/)

Use locale

> Maintain the minimum button size and margin around the button. Be
>   mindful that the button title may vary in length depending on the
>   locale. Use the following values for guidance.